# Angular 2 roles and permissions

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-guards

I have used angular2 and laravel 5.3 in my project. in laravel when user logged in server will be send the permissions of the user to handle authorization in angular. so I wrote a guard to protect routes from users that cannot access.
here is my guard class code:

```
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate{

permissions;
currentRoute;
constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router:Router){
    this.permissions = this.authService.getPermissions();
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    return this.checkHavePermission(state.url);
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    return this.checkHavePermission(state.url);
}

private checkHavePermission(url){
    switch (true) {
        case url.match(/^\/panel\/users[\/.*]?/):
            return this.getPermission('user.view');
        case url.match(/^\/panel\/dashboard/):
            return true;
        case url.match(/^\/panel\/permissions/):
            return this.getPermission('permissions.manager');
        case url.match(/^\/panel\/candidates[\/.*]?/):
            return this.getPermission('candidate.view');
    }
}


getPermission(perm){
    for(var i=0;i<this.permissions.length;i++){
        if(this.permissions[i].name == perm ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Now that the routes are secured I wondering that how can I access the user permission inside component class. Because sometimes user can access to a route but he can't see a specific part of dom. how can I handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should store the permissions in the service itself instead of in the guard.

So when the use authenticates, you store the permission in a property of the Authentication Service.  Then in the guard, you call the `this.authService.<property>` to use the permission.  In any other component, you can do the same, `this.authService.<property`> to get the user's permission level

Since the service will be passed around as a singleton, all components will have access to the same property.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when user reload's the page what about that. I thought that save the permissions in the local storage but it not secure. what you suggest?

Comment: Local Storage/Session Storage would be your option for that, but only store what you need to, clearly not the username/password combo. I'm sure there would be a way to do it with something like JWT, but I have no experience with that yet.

Comment: JWT is the trending method of storing authentication securely on the client.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the @Dave V response, you can implement your own "can" service which makes a little the code more readable. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserCan {

  constructor (private _auth: AuthService)
  {

  }

  public canDoWhatever()
  {
    return (this._auth.roles.indexOf("Whatever") > -1);
  }

}
```

And in your `Component` s you can inject it:

```
export class YourComponent {
  private canDoWhatever: boolean;

  constructor(private _userCan: UserCan) {
    this.canDoWhatever = _userCan.canDoWhatever();
  }

}
```

And finally in your html:

```
<div *ngIf="canDoWhatever">
```

Comment: I would like to know if this is the best way, because it looks awesome and cleaner

Answer (score 3):

For somebody who is looking for the library, you can check out [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions). It will remove an element from DOM, **lazy module compatible, isolated module compatible, else then syntax** is supported.

Add library

```
  @NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
     NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()
  ],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Load permissions

```
constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
       private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"];

    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm);

     this.http.get('url').subscribe((permissions) => {
       //const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"]; example of permissions
       this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions);
    })
  }
```

Use in templates

```
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']">
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
</div>
```

For better documentation, visit [wiki page](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/wiki).